# what exactly we can do with a MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

I have searched a lot about exactly how the MAC address can be useful for hacking and security testing but I didn't find anything. In movies it is like a key to the gate but I didn't find any tutorial or something that shows how a MAC address is useful for testing and....

Even when we can change MAC address: How exactly can that help for penetration testing?

Comment: It's not very useful from distant, but you can do all nice tricks locally on the same subnet, as the L2 _ethernet frames_ travels based on the MAC address instead of the IP address. One concrete example are techniques to see frames that are supposed to be sent to another port on a switch.